# mysqli num_rows returning zero

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm new to mysqli
trying to select everything from a table but num_rows function is returning 0
what am i doing wrong?

here is my code

```
    <?php $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'paa');
    $sql='SELECT * FROM utilisateurs';
    $rs=$conn->query($sql);
    if($rs === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: '.$sql.'Error:'.$conn>error,E_USER_ERROR);
      } else {
      $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
      echo $rows_returned;
      }

   ?>
```

Comment: Duplicate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538891/php-mysqli-num-rows-always-returns-0

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `$conn>error,E_USER_ERROR` which should be `$conn->error,E_USER_ERROR` there is no error in your code. Maybe the table is empty?

Comment: the table is not empty :/ i can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: I ran the code on my local machine (default PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04) with a real table it gave the correct result. IMHO the code is not the problem unless this is related to a bug in a specific PHP version. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the number of rows found by the query. 0 means that your query returned no rows.

The question why did it so is neither on topic not have any means to be answered.