# PHP Mysqli statement returns a single row, -1 rows affected, and no error

Tags: php, mysqli

This is so baffling I MUST be missing something simple. I have a query that checks to see if the transaction I'm inserting already exists in order to prevent duplicates. Here's the code:

```
function isaDupe($portableDB, $transactArray)
{
    $ref = $transactArray["reference"];
    $date = $transactArray["qdate"];
    $time =  $transactArray["time"];

  //prints the query so I can run by hand to test
    print "SELECT `counter` FROM transactions WHERE (`reference` = '$ref' AND `qdate` = '$date' AND `time` = '$time') ";

    if ($dupeSelectStmt = $portableDB->prepare("SELECT `counter` FROM transactions WHERE (`reference` = ? AND `qdate` = ? AND `time` = ?)"))
    {
        $dupeSelectStmt->bind_param('sss',$ref, $date, $time);
        $dupeSelectStmt->bind_result($counter);
        $dupeSelectStmt->execute();

        while ($dupeSelectStmt->fetch())
        {
            break;
        }

        $numRows = $portableDB->affected_rows;

        if ($numRows > 0)
            return TRUE;
        else if ($numRows == -1)
        {
            print " ERROR: ";
            print_r($portableDB->error);
            print_r($dupeSelectStmt->error);
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
            return FALSE;
    }
}
```

-If I run the query by hand through Workbench on the same server, I get 24 rows returned.

--this is the same if I prepare, set, and execute the statement by hand.

-affected_rows returns -1

--same if I do num_rows on the statement

-there is no error stored on the Statement or MySQLi object.

-if I put a print in the fetch() statement, it prints one row's worth of data

-if I store the fetched rows into an array and count the results, it's 1

-I've tried running it with each variable separately, same thing.

-other queries on the same server (heck, on the same MySQLi object) are working fine. SELECTS, UPDATES, and INSERTS.

Comment: You mention that it's working for other queries, do they have multiple row responses as well?

Comment: yes, and they're done via the same MySQLi constructor

Comment: Does your actual code have the while (fetch) not do anything? If you echo each row?

    while ($row = $dupeSelectStmt->fetch())) {
        print_r($row);
    }

Comment: aha! I forgot $stmt->store_result(); after executing!

Comment: Thanks for posting this question; found the same question and solution here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5016253/469643

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is I was forgetting to call mysqlistmt::store_result after mysqlistmt::execute().

Once I added $dupSelectStmt->store_result(); I was able to call $dupSelectStmt->num_rows and $portableDB->affected_rows and they both showed the 24 I knew I should be seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You need you use `$dupeSelectStmt->num_rows()` to get the number of rows in the result set for a SELECT.  You need to call either `affected_rows` (for INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE) or `num_rows()` on the `mysqli_stmt` object not not on the database handle (`$portableDB`) as you are currently doing.

Comment: b.) I mentioned I've tried num_rows as well. The issue was not calling "Store_results"

Comment: @RembrandtQ.Einstein I don;t think you are correct.  This is straight from PHP manual: `This function only works with queries which update a table. In order to get the number of rows from a SELECT query, use mysqli_stmt_num_rows() instead.`  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php   I meant the part about `affected_rows()` working like `num_rows()` on SELECT.  You are correct about the issue with not calling `store_results()`.

Comment: that's for a statement. If you're calling affected rows on a mysqli object it works just like num_rows: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php. Besides, that was doing the same thing without Store_result! Why exactly do I need to call store_result? I looked into that but the documentation says it's used for mysqli_data_seek() which I'm obviously not using.

Comment: @RembrandtQ.Einstein Ah yes you can use the `mysql->affected_rows()` in that manner.  My thoughts has always been that it's best to use the `mysqli_stmt` functions though as they are specific to the specific prepared statement that was executed as opposed to the last operation on the connection.

Comment: In regards to `mysqli->store_result()`, I am not sure that is is required, unless you wanted to buffer the data on the client (in this case your app server). The difference is if `store_result` is used before `fetch` the fetch operation will work with the entire result set that is in memory, providing better performance than having to load and remove each result set row in memory as you loop through the set. Of course this means that using `store_result` utilizes more memory, so if you will have a large result set which could impact server's memory usage, you might want unbuffered data.

Comment: Note that the `mysqli->fetch()` documentation shows examples which do not use `store_result()`, so it is acceptable to do without.  You do however need to move your `bind_result()` call after `execute()`.