# PHP mysqli affected_rows method seems to have a bug

Tags: php, mysqli, rows-affected

I'm getting an odd result, the following is the state of the mysqli object after a simple update query:

```
"UPDATE charstate SET name = '-', type = 'The Homemaker' WHERE gameno = 1"
```

As you see the affected_rows = -1 but... the info is "Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0"
And the query has updated the database.
I am using mysqli->affected_rows to check the success which is returning -1 and failing my test but that is incorrect.

Any ideas?

```
mysqli object {
  affected_rows => (int) -1
  client_info => (string) mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: 
  client_version => (int) 50010
  connect_errno => (int) 0
  connect_error => null
  errno => (int) 0
  error => (string)
  error_list => array(0)
  field_count => (int) 0
  host_info => (string) 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
  info => (string) Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0
  insert_id => (int) 0
  server_info => (string) 5.5.27
  server_version => (int) 50527
  stat => (string) Uptime: 11431  Threads: 6  Questions: 542  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 52  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 2  Queries per second avg: 0.047
  sqlstate => (string) 00000
  protocol_version => (int) 10
  thread_id => (int) 114
  warning_count => (int) ...
```

Comment: Are you very sure that the query really did succeed? The docs clearly say that an "affected_rows" value of -1 means that the query returned some kind of error.

Comment: @Cmdr I thought the same thing, but `errno` is clearly `0`, it can't be that

Comment: Maybe it's this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569862/php-mysqli-statement-returns-a-single-row-1-rows-affected-and-no-error Are you using mysqli's prepared statements?

Comment: Nope, not a prepared statement, just mysqli->query($query).  I do have the mysqli object in a parent class, so it is actually $this->mysqli->query($query);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior above appears when using "root" as the mysql user login (without password).
When using another user the affected_rows is correctly given.

Weird!
Seems this is a bug of some sort in mysql or PHP.
I don't know which or how to report that to whom.

Comment: The described behaviour is indeed strange. what versions of PHP and mySQL are you using? Make sure you're on the latest patch releases of both before even thinking of submitting a bug report. If you do submit a bug report, I'd submit it to PHP in the first instance, unless you can replicate the problem through another method outside of PHP. Oh, and doing *anything* with "root" and no password is a really bad idea. Even on your dev box. Just sayin'.

Comment: MySQL version 5.5.27 and PHP version 5.4.7 - this is under XAMPP on Windows though, I haven't tested elsewhere in the exact conditions.  Still pretty odd.