# Only single row is getting fetched from phpmyadmin table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I' m using the following code to get the desired details,that is, all the books that have the highest total count in order to show the most trending/popular books  present in a website. The total column depicts the no. of times a particular book had been viewed by an user of the website. Here is the code`

```
<?php    
include("connection.php");
global $con;
$sql1= "SELECT book FROM vi_views ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 3";
$query1= mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
if (!$query1)
{
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
  exit();
}
$obj1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1,MYSQLI_BOTH);
$row1=mysqli_num_rows($query1);
if ($row1>0)
{
  echo var_dump($obj1);
}
?>
```

Here is a look of how my table looks

**Table:vi_views**

```
id  book  course  date  total

1   book1  null  dd//mm/yy 3   
2   null   course1 dd/mm/yy 1    
3  book2   null dd/mm/yy 8
```

and so on....

The **problem** is that the query is working but only the first record according to the query is shown, that is, book2 in this case and no more books are showing. where I'm lacking in my code please tell...

Comment: you need to loop through the results and display them

Comment: people are trying to help you with answers but you not active

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MYSQLI num rows returning 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016253/php-mysqli-num-rows-returning-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql1= "SELECT book FROM vi_views ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 3";
$query1= mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

or

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    //print_r($row);
    $book=$row['book'];echo "<br/>";
    echo $book;
}
```

> output:

book1

book2

book3

Comment: Sorry but it's showing Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_assoc.

Comment: mysql_* functions have been removed in PHP7

Comment: code running but is there any other way out rather than using print_r function as i need to show individual results of the array in different <p> tags out in my website

Comment: i used list($book1, $book2)=$row['book'];
echo $book1."<br>".$book2;  but the page is blank..not showing any errors or results

Comment: your updated answer is printing all values of that particular column at a time, however, i want that the result get store in some kind of array variable or list() such that i can print only individual result i want to...is it possible? plzz help me out

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop though the rows returned after execution of query.

```
$rowCount=mysqli_num_rows($query1);
if ($rowCount > 0)
{
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo var_dump($row);  // Can do something what you want to with data
  }
} else {
  echo 'No records';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$obj1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1,MYSQLI_BOTH);` to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){ //do stuff }` With fetch array you get only one row at the time

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$obj1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1,MYSQLI_BOTH);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
  $book=$row['book'];
  echo var_dump($book);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop the result.

```
$rowCount=mysqli_num_rows($query1);
if ($rowCount > 0)
{
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```